# Language switch and firefox hotkey

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox, 23.04

I switched from windows to ubuntu and confused with keyboard language switch key combination. By default there is 'windows' key and spacebar. On windows I'm used Ctrl + Shift. So I change default behavior to my favorite in terminal using this commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Control>Shift_L']"
```

But now in Firefox I can't reopen closed window via hotkey Ctrl + Shift + T. System triggers on first two buttons and switch language. Is there is a workaround to save preferred combination of keys and use performance of hot keys in Firefox?

Comment: have to tried an alternative solution? Install Firefox View. Go to the hamburger menu > More tools > Customise toolbar and select it from there. It adds a FF icon on the left of the task bar. This utility will allow you to reopen recently closed tabs.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Ctrl+Shift conflicts so many other shortcuts of applications. Why don't you use Ctrl+Space or Alt+Shift instead?